# Connect two virtualbox machine

Tags: networking, virtualbox, lan

I have a virtual machine attached to NAT. It has the default IP 10.0.2.15. Now I create another machine but the new machine still has the same IP address 10.0.2.15. Is there a way that I can keep the network setting for the first machine, change the second machine's IP to something like 10.0.3.15 and make those two machine able to ping to each other (as in a LAN network) ?

Comment: This question is offtoppic here. You can ask it in https://superuser.com or https://serverfault.com

Answer (score 7):

## Solution

Use `NAT Network` instead of `NAT`.

This worked for me with VirtualBox version 5.2.22 and Redhat/Ubuntu.
The VM's had different IP's and both had access to internet.

For, both VM's :

1. turn them off
2. right-click the VM -> setting -> network :
   select `Nat Network` in `attached to`
   select `Allow VMs` in `Promiscuous mode` (advanced chevron)
3. turn them on
4. use `ifconfig` (or `ip addr`) command to find out each VM IP. In my case : 10.0.2.4 and 10.0.2.5

The following table provides an overview of the most important networking modes:

```
|          | VM <-> Host | VM1 <-> VM2 | VM -> Internet | VM <- Internet |
|----------|-------------|-------------|----------------|----------------|
| HostOnly | Yes         | Yes         | No             | No             |
| Internal | No          | Yes         | No             | No             |
| Bridged  | Yes         | Yes         | Yes            | Yes            |
| NAT      | No          | No          | Yes            | Port forward   |
| NATNet   | No          | Yes         | Yes            | Port forward   |
```

**NB:** If you want to connect to the VMs with tty, you need to do ip forwarding.

In the Virtualbox config:

- `File` -> `Preference` -> `Network` -> double-clic `Natnetwork` -> `port fordwarding` -> add a rule : host ip `127.0.0.1`, port `23` (or whatever to put in tty), Guest IP (the VM ip, example: `10.0.2.5`), guest port `22`

[More explanation here](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html)

Answer (score 1):

You cant do that one. 
You should use different networking type to connect two virtual machines.
I suggest you to use internal networking/bridged networking.

Ref:
http://trainenv.blogspot.in/2016/03/virtual-networking.html